# Can I bring features of an Android game into another Android game?

Tags: android, legal, modding

Platform : Android

Overview : Fifa 14 by EA sports has a manager mode, kick off and tournament mode in it, which was the last game of its series on android to have these features. Fifa 16 has great graphics, better controls and much more but it lacks the manager mode, kick off, tournament mode and is completely online.

Question : Is it possible to replicate the manager mode, kick off, tournament mode (by replicate I mean to code these features or copy paste them with or without modification from fifa 14 to fifa 16). Fifa 14 has been taken out from play store, so I think it is fine if this mod is made. And yeah, this is only for non commercial use. Please can someone experienced put light to this matter.Also please specify how, I am a complete noob.

Comment: I have both games obb and apk files. I am able to access all the files of both the games. Please someone ?

Comment: I think you'd be better off starting with some beginner game development tutorials, building up your skills until you're able to make your own sports game with the combination of features you want. I'd estimate your chances of success, both in technical execution and legal soundness, would be much higher when going this route.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to replicate ...

These are two different software. Software like these can change *a lot* from version to version. So you can't assume that you'll be able to "copy-paste" code from a game to another. So no, don't expect it is possible.

> Fifa 14 has been taken out from play store, so I think it is fine if this mod is made.

This does not remove the license that is attached to the software. You would need to look at the specific licenses that come with the games, but here is an excerpt of what is [currently available online](http://tos.ea.com/legalapp/WEBTERMS/US/en/PC/) (emphasis mine):

> You may not access, copy, modify or distribute any EA Service, Content or Entitlements (as those terms are defined below), unless expressly authorized by EA or permitted by law. **You may not reverse engineer or attempt to extract or otherwise use source code** or other data from EA Services, unless expressly authorized by EA or permitted by law.

So no, even if it has been taken out from the store, you cannot dig into the app.

> And yeah, this is only for non commercial use.

This does not matter, a license is a license, and a copyright is a copyright, money involved or not, you are bound by the license, and you don't own the copyright.

> I have both games obb and apk files. I am able to access all the files of both the games.

I suspect that you have assets and binary files. The code, what glues the assets together and displays it on your phone, is compiled; you would need to decompile it and figure out what is going on. It could probably be done. But the license does not allow it.

---

What can you do? Write a new game including the features of both; try to figure out what are the elements that made you enjoy both games, and try to replicate them in your new game.

Comment: It is illegal ok. I feel I should leave it be ...

Comment: I do not want to create a new game. This is bad unfortunately that EA does not allow it

Comment: @Thinkgood Yes, it's unfortunate. I suspect EA is close to its brands, like any other big players out there (e.g. Nintendo), and to its money. And it's unfortunate they remove games and features that players like; EA has to weight and balance the cost of maintaining those and the profit they make out of it. No money? -> pull the plug.